# Especially Special

Tags: no-computers, chess

Here's a special and interesting chess problem that I came across the other day.

As usual, no using a computer and no Googling or anything like that for the solution. You must use your own brain power!

White checkmaes Black in 7 moves.

**Милошески, Бошко
Mihajloski, Zlatko, Novi temi 1975 Comm.**

[image]

Comment: I assume you mean forced mate in 7?

Comment: All of black's moves are determined by the game-state rather than black.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The position is legal

> Black played h5xg4 (or h4xg3, or h3xg2) after White played g2-g4-g5, and White took the bQ with dxe

2. The key move is

> 1.Ba4

Threatening

> 2.Bb6# or 2.Ne4#

Black can only defend with

> 1...b5 (giving an escape square on c6)

But then :

> 2.axb6ep! d5 (controlling e4)
>  3.exd6ep! e5+ (checking)
>  4.fxe6ep! f5 (controlling e4)
>  5.gxf6ep! g5+ (checking)
>  6.hxg6ep! ... White always renews the threat of Ne4#

Now after

> any sixth move by Black, White will mate with 7.Ne4#.

It is special because

> 5 consecutive en passant captures is quite possibly the record for a direct mate.

Comment: I was considering the knight move already on the 2nd move and couldn't find a convincing answer for white. I fed the position to an engine and it thinks that black is actually winning.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Why is Nxf6 not legal?

Comment: Whites 5th move was gxf6, so there is a pawn to take.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Maybe you should look at the position you posted. The knight can definitely go to f6 (or even better to g5 in 2nd move).

Comment: Updated the answer to match the adjusted problem. It is much easier to solve when there actually is a solution.

Comment: I think you really should proofread your last comment...